# Spring Data JDBC and LockTypes: PESSIMISTIC_WRITE vs PESSIMISTIC_READ

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jdbc, pessimistic-locking

I am using a PostgreSQL database with Spring Data JDBC in my Spring Boot application. When I wanted to introduce pessimistic locking to my `findSeatById` method in my SeatDAO, I thought if it is possible to use `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` and `PESSIMISTIC_READ` interchangeably.

My idea is that if we use `PESSIMISTIC_READ` as the underlying lock type on the derived query method `findBySeatId`, modifying operations are blocked, i.e. we can read the seat of the passed id without any other method altering it. When setting the lock type to `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE`, we block read operations, so that no other method can read the referenced seat during this locking period, which implies that no other method can also modify it, since the seat can not be read and hence, not modified.

So can we use `LockType.PESSIMISTIC_READ` and `LockType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` interchangeably?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't think an update to a value requires a read.